# Localization property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

What's the easiest way to see that given an affine variety $X$

$$ \frac{\{f \in K[X]_h | h \notin \mathfrak{m}_p  \}} \sim  \cong k[X]_{\mathfrak{m}_p}$$

where $\sim$ denotes the usual equivalence relation whereby $f$ and $g$ coincide if there exists a neighbourhood of $p$ where they are equal and the underscript indicates localization.

Comment: More generally, if $S$ is a multplicatively closed subset of a commutative ring $A$, then $S^{-1}R = \varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} R_f$. The statement you're after is a special case once translated into commutative algebra. One can prove the more general case by using universal properties of localisation and colimits.

Comment: Can you help me see how my statement comes from the one you mentioned? The direct limit would be my left hand side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that every neighbourhood of $p$ is contains a neighbourhood of the form $D(f)=X \setminus V(f)$. Thus the equivalence relation may also be stated as $f \sim g$ if and only if $f=g$ in $k[X]_h$ for some $h$ such that $(h) \subset (fg)$. This implies that the left hand side of your desired isomorphism may be written as
$$\varinjlim\limits_{f \notin \mathfrak{m}_p} k[X]_f$$
We now turn to a more general situation: suppose $A$ is a commutative ring and $S$ is a mulitplicatively closed subset. Then
$$S^{-1}A=\varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f$$
**Proof** We construct homomorphisms in both directions. Note that every $f \in S$ is a unit in $\varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f$, so we get a unique extension of the obvious homomorphism $A \to \varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f$ to $S^{-1}A \to \varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f$. On the other hand, for every $f \in S$, $f$ is a unit in $S^{-1}A$, so we get a morphism $A_f \to S^{-1}A$. The collection of these morphisms is compatible so that we get an induced morphism $\varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f \to S^{-1}A$. We can use the uniqueness part of the universal properties to show that these two morphisms are inverse to each other. The induced morphism $\varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f \to \varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f$ has the property that for any $f$, the composition with the structure morphism $A_f \to \varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f$ yields that very structure morphism. But the indentity also satisfies this property, so the morphism $\varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f\to \varinjlim\limits_{f \in S} A_f$ has to be the identity. The other direction is similar. Basically, use the fact that there is only one morphism $S^{-1}A \to S^{-1}A$ such that the composition with the canonical morphism $A \to S^{-1}A$ is that very canonical morphism, namely the identity on $S^{-1}A$.

I apologize if this is phrased too categorically. If you want to make it even more category-thereotic, you could simplify the proof by invoking the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: Why can't $f$ be 0 at $p$?